# What nation do the residents of Kyoshi Island belong to?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In season 1, episode 4, "The Warriors Of Kyoshi", Aang and his group visit Kyoshi Island.

Since the Island is Earth Kingdom territory, as can be seen in both maps attached, and since it is named after the last Earthbending avatar, you would expect the island's citizens to be dressed in green; however, they are all dressed in water tribe clothes.

I am pretty sure there is no specific reason or any explanation given in the show, but maybe someone has an interesting theory for why it is this way.

(Picture is taken from S01E04, 8:35)
[image]

World map, showing Kyoshi Island, at the south end of the Earth Kingdom territory:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Kyoshi Island is technically Earth Kingdom territory. Their clothing choice might stem from their fighting style though;

Taken from the [wiki](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Kyoshi_Island):

> The Kyoshi Warriors are several all-female groups of fighters that are
>   fiercely protective of the island and its people, with the most
>   notable group led by Suki. While each village has its own forms and
>   traditions, their fighting style with metal fans and clothing
>   generally mimic those of Avatar Kyoshi. **Their fighting philosophy
>   emulates that of waterbenders, as it is based on the principle of
>   using their opponents' force against them.** The female warriors do not
>   take kindly to training outsiders, especially men, in these unique
>   methods.

However, the Kyoshi warriors wear Earth Kingdomish garb, and it is only the normal people that wear water tribe clothes, so this might be irrelevent.

Comment: It's an interesting theory about Kyoshi warriors' fighting is inspired by waterbenders, I did not know about it. However, the other part is not possible. The citizens are wearing blue in the picture, and at that time they still think the group is enemies and have them tied up.

Comment: Ah ok I will remove that part from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

They seem to consider themselves independent.

In the comic *Suki, Alone*, a character suggests buying supplies from "other nations." This could be read as "nations other than the Earth Kingdom," but I argue that wouldn't fully make sense. As the Air Nomads no longer exist and the Fire Nation is at war with the rest of the world, she's likely referring to the Earth Kingdom and the Water Tribes. This is supported by Suki stating the importance of Kyoshi removing their island from the mainland. They are separate from the entire world, including the Earth Kingdom.

[image]

That sentiment is repeated later on.

[image]

Additionally, in the episode "The Earth King," King Kuei refers to the Kyoshi Warriors as "our esteemed allies." It would be odd to refer to your own subjects that way.

Series co-creator Bryan Konietzco also refers to the island as "an isolationist society" in *ATLA: The Art of the Animated Series*.

The same book also translates Kyoshi's tapestry as saying

> On this day, Avatar Kyoshi splits from the mainland and creates Kyoshi Island. Let's hope our citizens' culture will be isolated from the tyranny of the world forever.

[image]